# group inside sql code rather than in cfoutput

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, group-by, cfoutput

I have a sql-server code of cities as rows and months as columns, there are sums by months but there are no sum by the `city_id`, I mean I have to count all the sum by city inside the output, and group it by `city_id`, anyway here is the sql code:

```
SELECT 
    SC.CITY_ID,SC.CITY_NAME, DATEPART(MM,I.INVOICE_DATE) AS INVOICE_MONTH,
    JAN=SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MM,I.INVOICE_DATE)=1 THEN COALESCE(NETTOTAL,0) ELSE 0 END),
    FEB=SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MM,I.INVOICE_DATE)=2 THEN COALESCE(NETTOTAL,0) ELSE 0 END),
    MAR=SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MM,I.INVOICE_DATE)=3 THEN COALESCE(NETTOTAL,0) ELSE 0 END),
    APR=SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MM,I.INVOICE_DATE)=4 THEN COALESCE(NETTOTAL,0) ELSE 0 END),
    MAY=SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MM,I.INVOICE_DATE)=5 THEN COALESCE(NETTOTAL,0) ELSE 0 END),
    JUN=SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MM,I.INVOICE_DATE)=6 THEN COALESCE(NETTOTAL,0) ELSE 0 END),
    JUL=SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MM,I.INVOICE_DATE)=7 THEN COALESCE(NETTOTAL,0) ELSE 0 END),
    AUG=SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MM,I.INVOICE_DATE)=8 THEN COALESCE(NETTOTAL,0) ELSE 0 END),
    SEP=SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MM,I.INVOICE_DATE)=9 THEN COALESCE(NETTOTAL,0) ELSE 0 END),
    OCT=SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MM,I.INVOICE_DATE)=10 THEN COALESCE(NETTOTAL,0) ELSE 0 END),
    NOV=SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MM,I.INVOICE_DATE)=11 THEN COALESCE(NETTOTAL,0) ELSE 0 END),
    DEC=SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MM,I.INVOICE_DATE)=12 THEN COALESCE(NETTOTAL,0) ELSE 0 END)
FROM 
    SETUP_CITY SC
    LEFT OUTER JOIN COMPANY C ON C.CITY = SC.CITY_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #DSN2_ALIAS#.INVOICE I ON I.COMPANY_ID = C.COMPANY_ID AND I.INVOICE_CAT IN (50,52,53,531,532,56,58,561,54,55,51,63,48) AND I.PURCHASE_SALES = 1
WHERE SC.COUNTRY_ID=1
GROUP BY SC.CITY_ID,SC.CITY_NAME,I.INVOICE_DATE
ORDER BY SC.CITY_ID,SC.CITY_NAME,I.INVOICE_DATE
```

and output:

`<cfoutput query="get_top_sales_TOTAL" group="CITY_ID">`

If I don't define the group by `city_id`, there are multiple rows of one city displayed. How is it possible to group the values (sum up) inside the sql code? So that I won't have to use the group statement inside the cfoutput?

Here is the screenshots to make it more clear, here's the screenshot with defined `group="city_id"`

[image]

If I don't define the `group="city_id"`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark is right about the invoice_month, there is no point for doing this. Your "correct" sql should be

```
SELECT 
        SC.CITY_ID,SC.CITY_NAME,
        TOTAL=SUM(COALESCE(NETTOTAL,0)),
        JAN=SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MM,I.INVOICE_DATE)=1 THEN COALESCE(NETTOTAL,0) ELSE 0 END),
        FEB=SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MM,I.INVOICE_DATE)=2 THEN COALESCE(NETTOTAL,0) ELSE 0 END),
        MAR=SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MM,I.INVOICE_DATE)=3 THEN COALESCE(NETTOTAL,0) ELSE 0 END),
        APR=SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MM,I.INVOICE_DATE)=4 THEN COALESCE(NETTOTAL,0) ELSE 0 END),
        MAY=SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MM,I.INVOICE_DATE)=5 THEN COALESCE(NETTOTAL,0) ELSE 0 END),
        JUN=SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MM,I.INVOICE_DATE)=6 THEN COALESCE(NETTOTAL,0) ELSE 0 END),
        JUL=SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MM,I.INVOICE_DATE)=7 THEN COALESCE(NETTOTAL,0) ELSE 0 END),
        AUG=SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MM,I.INVOICE_DATE)=8 THEN COALESCE(NETTOTAL,0) ELSE 0 END),
        SEP=SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MM,I.INVOICE_DATE)=9 THEN COALESCE(NETTOTAL,0) ELSE 0 END),
        OCT=SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MM,I.INVOICE_DATE)=10 THEN COALESCE(NETTOTAL,0) ELSE 0 END),
        NOV=SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MM,I.INVOICE_DATE)=11 THEN COALESCE(NETTOTAL,0) ELSE 0 END),
        DEC=SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MM,I.INVOICE_DATE)=12 THEN COALESCE(NETTOTAL,0) ELSE 0 END)
FROM 
        SETUP_CITY SC
            LEFT OUTER JOIN COMPANY C ON C.CITY = SC.CITY_ID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN #DSN2_ALIAS#.INVOICE I ON I.COMPANY_ID = C.COMPANY_ID 
                    AND I.INVOICE_CAT IN (50,52,53,531,532,56,58,561,54,55,51,63,48) 
                    AND I.PURCHASE_SALES = 1
WHERE  SC.COUNTRY_ID=1
GROUP BY SC.CITY_ID, SC.CITY_NAME
ORDER BY SC.CITY_ID,SC.CITY_NAME
```

Comment: The total is for a given city (all months/years). If you don't need it, just remove it and it should work fine as expected, no? Or just do a screenshot to see what's happening.

Comment: oh! :) didnt notice u've removed the invoice_month ) it helped! thank you! get a plus and correct answer! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that "invoice_date" in the group by and order by are going to produce multiple rows. Try this:

```
GROUP BY SC.CITY_ID, SC.CITY_NAME, DATEPART(MM,I.INVOICE_DATE)
ORDER BY SC.CITY_ID, SC.CITY_NAME,  INVOICE_MONTH
```

Can't try it so I can't debug it - but basically your GROUP can't have individual items in it that expand the uniqueness of the row (as an "invoice date" would likely do). Good luck!

Comment: thank you, this one actually did help a bit, but didn't solve the problem :(